# Java reduce methods into one?

Tags: java

Could somebody tell me if its possible to reduce the amount of methods in my class by doing something like the following to make 2 classes into 1:

```
public void duplicateEntries(String personName, String entryType) throws CustomException
{
    for (Entry entry : allEntries)
    {
        if ( entry instanceof entryType)
        {
            if (personName.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getName()))
            {
                throw new CustomException("\nAn entry for " + 
                personName + "already exists. Entry has been cancelled.");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Doesnt compile, the compiler reports "cannot find symbol - entryType" on line:

```
if ( entry instanceof entryType)
```

Original Code:

```
public void duplicatePersonal(String personName) throws CustomException
    {
        for (Entry entry : allEntries)
        {
            if ( entry instanceof Personal)
            {
                if (personName.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getName()))
                {
                    throw new CustomException("\nAn entry for " + 
                    personName + "already exists. Entry has been cancelled.");
               }
            }

        }
    }

    public void duplicateBusiness(String personName) throws CustomException
    {
        for (Entry entry : allEntries)
        {
            if ( entry instanceof Business)
            {
                if (personName.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getName()))
                {
                    throw new CustomException("\nAn entry for " + 
                    personName + "already exists. Entry has been cancelled.");
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

I know its not minimising my code by much but there is a few methods like this that I could also apply it to.

Comment: *"it complains about the class variable"*  If by 'it' you mean the compiler, it does not complain, just report.  Speaking of which, when it reports erros, copy/paste them rather than paraphrase them.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me, looks like you only need to check duplicate entries by name. just loop through the entries and check the equality of name against argument.

Comment: @LakshithaRanasingha there are 2 types of entries - A business entry and a personal entry. I only want to check for duplicates in the same entry. So a person could have a business entry and a personal entry but cannot have more than 1 of each. Thats why I need to check the type of the entry. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You could just store the entries in some kind of Map-ish datastructure. As I suggested in an earlier question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you pass the type of the thing you want to find duplicates for?

It could be something like

```
public boolean hasDuplicates(String name, Class type) {
    for (Entry entry : allEntries) {
        if (type.isInstance(entry) && name.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I would not rely on throwing an `Exception` if a duplicate is found because if you're looking for duplicates then it means that there could be duplicates, so it's not that exceptional :D

Of course I don't know what you're using this for and maybe passing `Object type` isn't that good, but after you write this you could always come up with a better solution.

You would use this like the following:

```
if (hasDuplicates(name, Personal.class)) {
    // handle duplicates
}
```

Comment: @albertozaccagni How do I pass my arrayList type? If I use your example above I just keep getting a compile error of "cannot find symbol - class type"

Comment: @albertozaccagni Sorry I should of explained better, I mean I cannot get the hasDuplicates method to compile. It reports "cannot find symbol - class type" on line: if ( entry instanceof type.. appologies if I have missed something this is my first time using java.

Comment: Totally my fault, see my fixed answer, sorry about that :P

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni thank you. I should of clicked on, the user below had put that in his post an I never noticed it. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni on the subject of passing the type is it possible to store the type in a variable to add to my arrayList. So instead of using entry = new Personal(firstName, lastName, street, town, postcode.toUpperCase(), dob); I could use something like entry = new type(firstName, lastName, street, town, postcode.toUpperCase(), dob);?

Comment: No, that is not possible in Java. The compiler will try to find a class named `type` and yell at you because it can't find it.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni no worries thanks for letting me know. Was getting nowhere with google an that will be why =)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this could work:

```
public void verifyUnique(String entryName, Class<? extends Entry> type) throws CustomException {
    for (Entry entry : allEntries) {
        if (type.isInstance(entry) && entryName.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getName()) {
           throw new CustomException("An entry for " + entryName " already exists");
        }
    }
}

...
verifyUnique("name", Personal.class);
```

This is not very elegant though. I'd rather add a getter getType() that returns an enum to Entry.

```
public void verifyUnique(String entryName, EntryType type) throws CustomException {
    for (Entry entry : allEntries) {
        if (entry.getType() == type && entryName.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getName()) {
           throw new CustomException("An entry for " + entryName " already exists");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of creating a getType method. Never used enum but will give it a go. Thanks